# Guaranteeing uniqueness of solution of ODE.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

Given the $n$th order ODE:

$$\sum _{0\leq i \leq n}a_ix^{(i)}=0,\quad x(t_1) = \xi_1, x^{(1)}(t_2)=\xi_2,\ldots,x^{(n-1)}(t_{n-1})=\xi_{n-1} $$

I know that if $t_1=\cdots=t_{n-1}$, then uniqueness of solutions is guaranteed.

But what if $t_i\neq t_j\forall j\neq i $. Is there a way to find bounds on the differences of the $t_i$'s to guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: try to google for a "existence and uniqueness theorem for Delay differential equation". I'm not an expert in DDE, so I'm not sure if there is such a theorem for a general case. For some cases it is definitely exists, e.g. https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigy6uyg6_JAhVB6xQKHa0jCmcQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F2028307&usg=AFQjCNEY9hI0zxJk_KkaxqtWeMPTFtEZlw&sig2=UVa4a4YVIZsDGkem7EHy-g